# AJAX: how do i get around the problem of needing synchronous requests?

Tags: php, ajax, asynchronous

I'm deleting a previously asked question and asking again more succinctly now that I have a bit more understanding of the problem.

I have a page that uses a lot of AJAX and is updated and dynamically populated with content (form elements and div's with text returned from other form element).

I really need to be able force users to wait until AJAX requests are processed (for example after they have completed a text field that has submitted some values) before they continue. From what I gather using synchronous requests can cause problems with the browser hanging etc...

I also need to have a javascript function that executes multiple AJAX function calls but i also need them to execute one at a time. Currently using asynchronous calls produces unpredictable results... maybe I'm going about this the wrong way. There is a lot of code so it's hard to provide a short example  but I'll give it a try below:

The from below (which is itself inserted by an Ajax function) dynamically adds more form elements to the page if it is the first time the input has been edited (first time the content is written to the database... subsequently it will just update the existing db entry and I don't need to add the additional form items)

```
   <form name='talkItemForm' id='talkItemFrom-<?php print $_POST[talkItemID]; ?>' class='talkItemForm' method='post'>

   <input type='hidden' id='talkItemID' name='talkItemID' value='<?php print $_POST[talkItemID]; ?>'><input type='hidden' id='talkID' name='talkID' value='<?php print $_POST[talkID]; ?>'>

   <input type='text' name='talkItemInput' id='talkItemInput' value='New Topic...'  onblur=" updateTalkItem(this.parentNode, '<?php print $_POST[talkID]; ?>', '<?php print $_POST[talkItemID]; ?>'); isNewTalkItem('<?php print $_POST[talkID]; ?>', '<?php print $_POST[talkItemID]; ?>', '<?php print generateTalkItemID()+1; ?>','<?php print generateNoteID(); ?>'); "/>

   </form>
```

Invokes:

```
   function isNewTalkItem (talkID, talkItemID, newTalkItemID, newNoteID){

      var url = "./wp-content/themes/twentyten/addBelowIfNew.php";

      var poststr = "talkItemID=" + talkItemID;

      http_request = false;
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari,...
         http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
         if (http_request.overrideMimeType) {
            // set type accordingly to anticipated content type
            //http_request.overrideMimeType('text/xml');
            http_request.overrideMimeType('text/html');
         }
      } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
         try {
            http_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
         } catch (e) {
            try {
               http_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {}
         }
      }
      if (!http_request) {
         alert('Cannot create XMLHTTP instance');
         return false;
      }

      http_request.onreadystatechange = function(){


           if (http_request.readyState == 4) {
               if (http_request.status == 200 || http_request.status == 0) {

                  result = http_request.responseText;

        //following code will note execute if this is not the first time this field has been edited... 
        if (result) {

                        // call to AJAX function that inserts a new <form>
            newNote(newNoteID, talkItemID);

                        // another call to AJAX function that inserts a new <form>
            newTalkItem(talkItemID, talkID);

        }

               } else {
                  alert('There was a problem with the request.');
               }

           }

      }    

      http_request.open('POST', url, true);
      http_request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      http_request.setRequestHeader("Content-length", poststr.length);
      http_request.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
      http_request.send(poststr);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**When I first stared to answer this question I incorrectly assumed you were using ajax. As Mikhail stated, you should really learn that, it makes things much easier, simpler, and cleaner**

I think I can pretty much answer both of your questions with similar answers.

As far as the first question, you're right, doing synchronous requests will lock up the browser process while it waits for the request to return. What you can do is either make it so the next part of the UI is invisible while you wait for the results to return or make it uneditable. Here is an example of an ajax request that could do that:

> $.ajax({ url: "test.html", context: document.body, success: function(){
>           // make ui editable
>         }});

Similarly, for your second question, you can just nest them:

> $.ajax({ url: "test.html", context: document.body, success: function(){
>
> ```
> $.ajax({ url: "test.html", context: document.body, success: function(){
>
>       $.ajax({ url: "test.html", context: document.body, success: function(){
>
>           $(this).addClass("done");
>
>       }});
>
>    }});
> ```
>
> }});

Comment: ahhh... this is brilliant. i'll give it a try. Thanks. I do know a little about jquery so i'll get implementing ajax with it too. I'm just getting stuck into developing a web app as a pet project. Stack Overflow is an amazing resource. i'll do my best to contribute (on things i do know a little about :) thanks guys. I needed a bit of advice/perspective here too. my head is just so full of php and javascript functions and variables and and requests and responses and database tables i couldn't see the wood for the trees.  thanks again. ...though i may yet be back :)

Answer (score 1):

There may be a better approach to solving your overall task, but several points can be made regardless:

1. Learn jquery and use that for your ajax -- cleaner syntax, easier to read and debug.
2. To make your users wait for ajax to be done set a flag before requesting a call, and unset it when ajax returns. Whatever functionality needs to wait for ajax answer check if the flag is set and abort the function call.
3. Waiting for previous ajax to finish before starting a new call sounds like a bad design. but to answer your question anyway -- you can create a chain of ajax calls such that each time data is loaded, a callback function starts the next ajax call.

Again, all of this is much easier through jquery. http://www.jquery.com/

Comment: Thanks for your response.    1) If using jquery is easier i will certainly do that.   2) That sounds good thanks.    3)maybe i dont need to do this... but what's currently happening is that only content from one of the AJAX requests is being inserted for some reason. If i alert any random value in one of the functions it seems that content from both requests is added after i click ok... so i assumed this must have something to do with one of the functions completing execution before the other one and somehow stopping the second function from completing. Sorry if that's confusing??!

Comment: I can't tell from your code if some of the variables you are using are global. If they are -- then multiple ajax calls populate the same variable when they return data. This is an obvious issue. JQuery provides object oriented solution for multiple ajax calls, so tracking variable scope is much easier.